# Bumps and bands in drywall

Tags: drywall, ceiling

Have started noticing these bands, bumps in the ceiling specially where the ceiling meets the walls or center where the two sides of the roof meet. None of the bulges/bands seem moist or mushy, we do have a few nail pops here and there. To my untrained eye seems like a bad drywall job and the house settling, but wanted to make sure if these are signs of roof leaking or any other structural issue I should be on the lookout for.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also noticed some cracks near the light fixtures and textured wall-ceiling joint
[image]
[image]
[image]

For reference this is a house that was constructed in 2018 and we live in Pacific Northwest (Seattle to be specific).

Outside of cosmetic issue, should I be worried about anything or looking in to getting it fixed?

Thank You!

Comment: Chance the house is still settling/or the drywall finish was not perfect.  Just cosmetic, and would wait till you are ready to repaint.  Patching now and painting to match will show up now like a sore thumb.

Comment: that's reassuring. Thank you @crip659

Comment: Clean your glasses less, or find more interesting things to look at. ;^)

Answer (score 2):

From buyersask.com:

Probably the most common cause is that there was insufficient drywall compound applied to the taped joint or improper application. i.e. the tape did not get properly embedded into the mud on a hot summer day. 2. Moisture or dampness may also cause the tape to come loose.

[Link to article](https://buyersask.com/interior/drywall/drywall-tape-loose-bubbles-or-wrinkled/#:%7E:text=Probably%20the%20most%20common%20cause,the%20tape%20to%20come%20loose.)

If moisture it causing the wrinkling, then that needs to be found and fixed. As for getting the tapes joints repaired, it is not structural, but more cosmetic, so if you don't like the way it looks, you can get a pro to give you an estimate or you can do it yourself.

[Here's](https://www.sfgate.com/homeandgarden/article/Sheetrock-tape-is-peeling-away-from-walls-2538233.php) an article on how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Build in 2018

probably with "young" wood means high moisture content.

It will dry up over the years, leading to shrinking.

The drywalls do not keep up with that.

The drywall tape has only cosmetic property, no structural, to cover the gaps.

There is much stronger tape used to prevent crack formation.

It is usually called drywall mesh tape.

[image: mesh tape]

It is easier to apply, since you can directly see the amount of mud used, and not have a common problem with not enough mud under the tape. The fibers provide additional strength. It also has a light adhesive on one side, to stick it to the drywall while you are working.

After all said, it is up to you if you want to replace the original tape.

Comment: Just for transpondian terminology translation - 'drywall mesh tape' is known in the UK as 'scrim'.